# Principal Ultrafilter contains a finite set

Tags: filters

Prove that an ultrafilter is principal if and only if it contains a finite set.

I can't quite figure out why and it may be because I don't have a clear understanding of a principal ultrafilter. I have read a few different definitions that don't seem to line up. Could someone clear up what a principal ultrafilter is?

Comment: I think you should (perhaps in a separate question) cite the deifnitions that don't seem to line up and then perhaps we can help you sort out the relations between them.

Comment: On what structure are you considering ultrafilters ? Just a set with normal inclusion and intersection or some other lattice structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a set, and let $x\in X$. The principal ultrafilter at $x$ is

$$\mathscr{U}_x=\{U\subseteq X:x\in U\}\,.$$

The principal ultrafilters on $X$ are precisely these ultrafilters $\mathscr{U}_x$ for $x\in X$.

Note that it’s always true that $\{x\}\in\mathscr{U}_x$, so clearly every principal ultrafilter on $X$ contains a finite set, even a singleton. Your real task is to show that if $F$ is a finite subset of $X$, $\mathscr{U}$ is an ultrafilter on $X$, and $F\in\mathscr{U}$, then $\mathscr{U}=\mathscr{U}_x$ for some $x\in X$. In other words, you must show that there is some $x\in X$ such that $\{x\}\in\mathscr{U}$.

HINT: In fact there is an $x\in F$ such that $\{x\}\in\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: This isn't the definition of principal ultrafilter that's normally used, although it is obviously equivalent. The normal definition is an ultrafilter $U$ such that there exists $z\in U$, for all $y\in U$, $z\leq y$.

Comment: @DonThousand: It’s the normal definition for ultrafilters on a set (or, if you prefer, ultrafilters on the Boolean algebra $\wp(X)$), and that appears to be the present context.

Comment: Is it? I learned this result as a theorem in the textbook I followed on logic.

Comment: @DonThousand: In my experience it is. My experience may of course be skewed, since I first learned about ultrafilters on sets and only later about ultrafilters on Boolean algebras in general.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to show this. "Your real task is to show that if  is a finite subset of ,  is an ultrafilter on , and ∈, then = for some ∈. In other words, you must show that there is some ∈ such that {}∈.

HINT: In fact there is an ∈ such that {}∈". Ultrafilters are maximal, thus if there exits a principal ultrafilter wouldn't they have to be the same? I get we would have to show this but I guess I am just not quite understanding.

Comment: @Kim: Show that if $U\in\mathscr{U}$, and $\{A,B\}$ is a partition of $U$, then exactly one of the sets $A$ and $B$ is in $\mathscr{U}$. HINT: If $A\notin\mathscr{U}$, then $I\setminus A\in\mathscr{U}$; now use the fact that $\mathscr{U}$ is closed under finite intersections. Once you have this result, apply it repeatedly to $F$: if $x\in F$, then either $\{x\}\in\mathscr{U}$, or $F\setminus\{x\}\in\mathscr{U}$.